# Angulardart should not make links reload

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In angularjs you can prohibit to reload a page when using.

```dart
<a href="" ng-click="..">text</a>
```

In angulardart the link is actually navigating to the href. Is that intended?

Goog examples of the angularjs behavior: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

```dart
<a id="link-1" href ng-click="value = 1">link 1</a> (link, don't reload)
```

Comment: I always used the anchor tag without the href/ng-href attribute when I wanted to create a button without route change (in angularJS) and it seems to me like it's working fine also in angularDart... does that meet your behavior requirements?

Comment: @doodeec that works but it turns the cursor into a text selector instead of a pointer which isn't very ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

```dart
<a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.clickHandler($event)">text</a>
```

.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

// ...

void clickHandler(MouseEvent event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // suppress default click action
  event.stopPropagation();  // 
  //event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // optional

  // do something else
}
```

**old answer**

I haven't used it myself yet but AngularDart has the NgHref directive

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/directive/ng_src_boolean.dart#L60

Comment: The ng-href is used so that expressions can be evaluated inside the href. When using the regular href the user would be able to click on a {{musthash}} at first. But in my case i want to disable the navigation all together and just invoke the ng-click.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The solution looks rather tedious i must say. Also i had to use stopPropagation(). Only using preventDefault() still performed the navigation.

Comment: Yes, this is the current workaround and I agree it's less than desirable. Maybe try this out: https://github.com/pavelgj/route.dart/commit/9534e7731302ded773d4a9611464813326620377

Comment: My answer may be outdated. I didn't work with Angular.dart for a while and don't know if better options became available in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to enable `NgRoutingUsePushState` which seems to not interfere with anchor links or ng-click at all. You just have to remove or comment out the following line in your RoutingModule:

```dart
//bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
```

To use push state you also have to have your webserver rewrite urls to `index.html`. It makes running the app on a local dev server a little more complex but I decided to go for it since I want that functionality eventually and because of this bug. An example nginx config is:

```dart
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.html
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
}
```

Note: Tested with Angular 0.13.0

Comment: Just be aware that everything needs to be referenced absolutely if you have nested routes such as `http://example.com/category/page`. I was having some weird issues where Chrome and Chromium were running out of memory because my component specified its `templateUrl` relatively instead of absolutely and the resource was not found. For example my code was `templateUrl: 'packages/mypackage/component/mycomponent.html'` when it should have been `templateUrl: '/packages/mypackage/component/mycomponent.html'`